# ViewPager call in Button any Fragment

Tags: android, button, android-viewpager, fragment, cardview

I defined two Fragmetns. In Fragment "B" I have one Button. When I click this Button I want to call Fragment "A" passing a parameter.

I want it so that when I click  https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html?hl=es

Comment: please look at [ask]

Answer (score 0):

put all your code of `fragment A` and `fragment B` in the container activity